# ios8 Swift SpriteKit - Pause and Resume NSTimers in swift

Tags: swift, timer, ios8, nstimer, invalidation

I have searched many times on the internet but could not find the answer to this question. I know how to pause and resume NSTimers by using the invalidate functions - timer.invalidate. and I know how to resume them. But I have a SpriteKit game. When I pause my game, I stop everything and the timers. I know that I can stop them using .invalidate but when I invalidate them:

For example lets say I have a 5 second timer that runs continously that spawns one block.

When the timer reaches second 3 of the cycle and when I paused the game, and invalidate the timers. When I resume, Now the timers second goes back to 0 and I must wait another 5 seconds. I want it to continue from where it left off, 3 , and wait 2 seconds for the block to spawn.

```
            blockGenerator.generationTimer?.invalidate()

            self.isGamePaused = true
            self.addChild(self.pauseText)

            self.runAction(SKAction.runBlock(self.pauseGame))
```

e`

and when I resume it:

```
blockGenerator.generationTimer = ...
```

I have to wait another 5 seconds, I want the timer to continue from where it left off

If you can help me, I appreciate it thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to pause/resume `Timer` instances, because using repeating timers we know the next `fire date`.

**This is a simple class `SRTimer` and a protocol `SRTimerDelegate`**

---

**Protocol SRTimerDelegate**

```
protocol SRTimerDelegate : AnyObject {
    func timerWillStart(_ timer : SRTimer)
    func timerDidFire(_ timer : SRTimer)
    func timerDidPause(_ timer : SRTimer)
    func timerWillResume(_ timer : SRTimer)
    func timerDidStop(_ timer : SRTimer)
}
```

**Class SRTimer**

```
class SRTimer : NSObject {
    
    var timer : Timer?
    var interval : TimeInterval
    var difference : TimeInterval = 0.0
    var delegate : SRTimerDelegate?
    
    init(interval: TimeInterval, delegate: SRTimerDelegate?)
    {
        self.interval = interval
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    @objc func start(_ aTimer : Timer?)
    {
        if aTimer != nil { fire(self) }
        if timer == nil {
            delegate?.timerWillStart(self)
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: interval, target: self, selector: #selector(fire), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }

    func pause()
    {
        if timer != nil {
            difference = timer!.fireDate.timeIntervalSince(Date())
            timer!.invalidate()
            timer = nil
            delegate?.timerDidPause(self)
        }
    }

    func resume()
    {
        if timer == nil {
            delegate?.timerWillResume(self)
            if difference == 0.0 {
                start(nil)
            } else {
                Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: difference, target: self, selector: #selector(start), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
                difference = 0.0
            }
        }
    }

    func stop()
    {
        if timer != nil {
            difference = 0.0
            timer!.invalidate()
            timer = nil
            delegate?.timerDidStop(self)
        }
    }
    
    @objc func fire(_ sender : SRTimer)
    {
        delegate?.timerDidFire(self)
    }

}
```

---

Make your class conform to the protocol `SRTimerDelegate` and initialize a `SRTimer` instance with

```
var timer : SRTimer!
timer = SRTimer(interval: 5.0, delegate: self)
```

---

**Methods**

`start()` calls the delegate method `timerWillStart` and starts the timer.

`pause()` saves the difference between the current date and the next fire date, invalidates the timer and calls the delegate method `timerDidPause`.

`resume()` calls the delegate method `timerWillResume`, creates a temporary one shot timer with the saved `difference` time interval. When this timer fires the main timer will be restarted.

`stop()` calls the delegate method `timerDidStop` and invalidates the timer.

When the timer fires, the delegate method `timerDidFire` is called.

Comment: @vadian, maybe I'm not seeing it but when `start()` gets called initially, what is the value of `interval`?...I don't see `interval` initialized to any value.

Comment: @Pangu You have to initialize an instance with `interval` and `delegate`

Comment: @vadian, I apologize for the ignorance, I'm still a bit new to using `NSTimers`...can you provide quick example?

Comment: Actually an example how to use the `Timer` class is in the answer above the `Methods` paragraph. Just declare a `Timer` property and create an instance. Then implement the delegate methods and call the instance  methods.

Comment: @Vadian So for example, I want to trigger an event repeatedly to run every 1 second (interval = 1).  but I call `pause` to pause the event at 1.5 seconds in. When I want to resume that event again, I call `resume`. Will this ensure that the event fires off 0.5 seconds later (remaining time) and continues firing every 1 second after that? Or will the event fire after 1 whole second?

Comment: It's supposed to fire 0.5 seconds later and then every 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me say this - it is not possible to do with just NSTimer, there is no inbuilt function to do that (you can build logic around that as the answer from Vadian suggests). BUT.

**Why NSTimer is not good idea**

Lets stop and think for a little. For game objects and precise spawning, you should never use `NSTimer` in the first place. The problem is implementation of `NSTimer` (quoting the docs):

> Because of the various input sources a typical run loop manages, the
>   effective resolution of the time interval for a timer is limited to on
>   the order of 50-100 milliseconds. If a timer’s firing time occurs
>   during a long callout or while the run loop is in a mode that is not
>   monitoring the timer, the timer does not fire until the next time the
>   run loop checks the timer. Therefore, the actual time at which the
>   timer fires potentially can be a significant period of time after the
>   scheduled firing time.

There are other problems with NSTimer but that is out of scope of that question.

**Solution**

What you can do instead, you should listen to delta time change in each update call

```
let delta = currentPreciseTime - previousPreciseTime
```

Now, when you have that delta, you can have your `counter : Double`, and on each update, you increase counter by delta.

```
let counter : Double
counter += delta
```

Now that your "timer" is running properly, you can check with simple condition if your period of time already passed, or do whatever you want with it:

```
let SPAWN_OBJECT_AFTER : Double = 5.0
if counter > SPAWN_OBJECT_AFTER {

    // Do something on fire event
    self.spawn()

    // This line effectively restarts timer
    counter -= SPAWN_OBJECT_AFTER
}
```

You can easily build your own, very easy timer class to do it. Also! This way you have control over what happens in your update call, which is where the update logic belongs. Timer breaks that model by allowing method execution outside that - it might be intended, but usually is not).

I built a games running in production every day and this is I'd say most common solution for periodic events, as it saves the most resources when used appropriately. Obviously not fitting for everything but definitely fits your need.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to pause/resume a NSTimer in the way you are talking about. You must use `timer.invalidate()` and `timer.fire()`. However, perhaps you can use an int (that starts at 5 and goes down every second) to keep track of how many seconds the initial timer has before fires again and once the times fires again, make sure the new int value is passed to start the initial timer from the correct point in time.