# Swift : Pause and Resume NSTimer

Tags: swift, nstimer

I know this has been posted before, but I'm new to swift and i would like to find help as per my situation.
So i need to run a timer, and when the stopMusic() is called(somewhere in my app), i need to pause the timer, then when the playMusic() is called, i need to resume the timer.

Here is what i have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

runFirstDropTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(38.2, target: self, selector: "runAnimation", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

}

func stopMusic() {
//Pause Timer
}

func playMusic() {
//Resume Timer
}
```

Thank you for any help you can provide!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. Timers can't be paused.

Instead you need to record the current time when you start the timer:

```
let startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
let interval = 38.2
//Start your timer 
runFirstDropTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(interval, 
  target: self, 
  selector: "runAnimation", 
  userInfo: nil, 
  repeats: false)
```

Then, when you want to pause your timer, invalidate it and figure out how much time is left:

```
runFirstDropTimer.invalidate()
let elapsed = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() - startTime
let remaining = interval - elapsed
```

And finally when you want to resume your timer create a new timer with the `remaining` value.

Comment: Great way to implement this! However, I'm having issue with the startTime. It says its some huge number when i print it. Essentially not the correct start time.

Comment: I again implemented this exactly how you wrote it, but my timer is off, it drops too much too fast. It'll be at 31 then drop to 20 when clearly 11 seconds have not gone by.

Comment: The number you see for startTime will be a huge number. It's the number of seconds since Jan 1, 2001. Add your code, including the methods where it is located, to the bottom of your question and describe what's going wrong.

Comment: Hi! I updated it, would you mind taking a look? Maybe I'm going wrong somewhere. So I'm pretty sure that if i do .fire() it will start it back up with the new timer since its value has changed. But solely concentrating on the firstDropInterval, its value changes weird and not consistently, aka, something is wrong. BTW i use static variables because i need these variables to be seen on a global scope.

Comment: Actually you can pause and resume repeating timers by getting the `fireDate` and calculate the difference to the actual time. When pausing the timer invalidate the repeating timer. When resuming the timer create another non repeating timer with the difference interval and then restart the repeating timer. See my answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933213/ios8-swift-spritekit-pause-and-resume-nstimers-in-swift/31945566?) topic.

Comment: @vadian, you can't really pause ANY timer. You can simulate the effect by invalidating it, then start a *new* timer (repeating or non-repeating) but it's a new timer. As you say, if you want to create a new repeating timer who's "phase" matches the previous timer that is possible with extra steps.

Comment: Hi @OriginalAlchemist I'm running into the exact same thing with you were. It seems my timer continues to run after the second pause is pressed. Could you please post your code to how you got it to work?

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 5.**

Resumable timer:

```
class ResumableTimer: NSObject {

    private var timer: Timer? = Timer()
    private var callback: () -> Void

    private var startTime: TimeInterval?
    private var elapsedTime: TimeInterval?

    // MARK: Init

    init(interval: Double, callback: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.callback = callback
        self.interval = interval
    }

    // MARK: API

    var isRepeatable: Bool = false
    var interval: Double = 0.0

    func isPaused() -> Bool {
        guard let timer = timer else { return false }
        return !timer.isValid
    }

    func start() {
        runTimer(interval: interval)
    }

    func pause() {
        elapsedTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - (startTime ?? 0.0)
        timer?.invalidate()
    }

    func resume() {
        interval -= elapsedTime ?? 0.0
        runTimer(interval: interval)
    }

    func invalidate() {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }

    func reset() {
        startTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
        runTimer(interval: interval)
    }

    // MARK: Private

    private func runTimer(interval: Double) {
        startTime = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: interval, repeats: isRepeatable) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.callback()
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**:

```
private var playTimer: ResumableTimer?

playTimer = ResumableTimer(interval: 5.0) { [weak self] in
   self?.doSomethingOnTimerFire()
}
playTimer?.start()
```

Comment: This code does not work in RunLoop.current.add() call like a regular Timer.  Is there a way to get this work that way because it never fires for me.