# Start, Pause, Resume NSTimer Swift

Tags: swift2, nstimer

I'd like to create a countdown timer feature where the user can pause and resume with the same button press. I know there have been several similar questions on SO including this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35809723/swift-pause-and-resume-nstimer) answered. However, I'm still stuck (2nd day). It seems that my timer is still ticking despite being invalidated.

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
var duration: NSTimeInterval { return Double((exercise!.duration))! * 60 }
var interval: Double?
var timer = NSTimer()
var startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
var elapsedTime: Double?
var timeLeft: Double?
var inProgress = false
var isPaused = false
var completionStatus = false


@IBAction func pressStart(sender: UIButton) {
    if inProgress{
        if isPaused {
            resumeAnimation(timeLeftShapeLayer)
            sender.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            print("pressed resume, with \(timeLeft!) time left")
            startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeLeft!, target: self, selector: #selector(PerformExerciseViewController.updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            isPaused = false

        } else {
            pauseAnimation(timeLeftShapeLayer)
            isPaused = true
            sender.setTitle("Resume", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            elapsedTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() - startTime
            timeLeft = duration - elapsedTime!
            timer.invalidate()

            print("pressed pause, with \(timeLeft!) time left")
        }
    } else {
        drawTimeLeftShape()
        timeLeftShapeLayer.addAnimation(strokeIt, forKey: nil)
        sender.setTitle("Pause", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(duration, target: self, selector: #selector(PerformExerciseViewController.updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        inProgress = true
        isPaused = false
    }
```

When printing the time:

pressed pause, with 56.3997309803963 time left  (long pause here, maybe 10 sec.)

pressed resume, with 56.3997309803963 time left (super short play time 0.1 sec.)

pressed pause, with 47.3651859760284 time left (seems like the time counted during the pause

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

I had calculated the remaining time wrong.
Instead of:

```
timeLeft = duration! - elapsedTime!
```

Use:

```
timeLeft = timeLeft! - elapsedTime!
```